# Why Fiddler and Wireshark doesn't capture request from NW.JS client?

Tags: web-applications, fiddler, wireshark, nw.js

I am debugging my web app and use NW.JS client (it's necessary). I want to see http requests via fiddler but I don't. Also I tried to use Wireshark and result was similar. But I can see requests from my web app if I use Chrome or Firefox.